# Error in a unit test mocking up the PDOStatement class with phpunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I am getting errors when launching unit tests because of the following mockup

CODE

```
$mockPDOStatement = $this->createMock(PDOStatement::class);
```

ERROR

```
Error: Call to undefined method ReflectionUnionType::getName()
```

PHP 8.1.1
PHPUnit 8.5.22

Complete example :

```
class Connection
{

    public function getPdo()
    {
        return new PDO(
            dbServer,
            dbUsername,
            dbPassword
        );
    }
}

class Events
{

    private $connection;

    public function __construct(Connection $connection)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    public function getEvent($id)
    {
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE id=:id';
        $pdo = $this->dbConnection->getPdo()->prepare($query);
        $pdo->execute(["id" => $id]);
        return $pdo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class EventsTest extends TestCase
{

    private $eventData = [
        'id' => '1',
        'Description' => '',
        'EndTime' => '2021-12-09 18:00:00',
        'IsAllDayEvent' => '0',
        'StartTime' => '2021-12-09 17:00:00',
        'Subject' => 'Prueba Creada desde Google',
    ];

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->eventd = new Events(
            $this->getConnectionMock(),
        );
    }

    public function testFetchMany()
    {
        $events = $this->eplanEventRepository->getEvent(1);
        $this->assertIsArray($events);
    }

    private function getConnectionMock()
    {

        $mockPDOStatement = $this->createMock(PDOStatement::class);

        $mockPDOStatement->method('fetchAll')
            ->willReturn($this->eventData);

        $mockPDO = $this->createMock(PDO::class);

        $mockPDO->method('prepare')
            ->willReturn($mockPDOStatement);

        $mock = $this->createMock(Connection::class);

        $mock->method('getPdo')
            ->willReturn($mockPDO);

        return $mock;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, what framework are you using (it seems it is Laravel)? Second, why are you trying to mock that? It seems that class is a Core class, so you don't mock core classes... Explain more what you want to achieve mocking that.

Comment: thanks for replying, I have updated my question with an example of what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me

private function getConnectionMock()
{

```
$mockPDOStatement = $this
   ->getMockBuilder("stdClass" /* or whatever has a fetchAll */)
   ->setMethods(array("fetchAll", "execute", "fetchColumn"))
   ->getMock();

$mockPDOStatement->method('fetchAll')
     ->willReturn($this->eventsData);

$mockPDOStatement->method('fetchColumn')
     ->willReturn(2);

$mockPDO = $this
   ->getMockBuilder("ThePDOObject")
   ->disableOriginalConstructor()
   ->setMethods(array("prepare", "lastInsertId"))
   ->getMock();

$mockPDO->method('prepare')
     ->willReturn($mockPDOStatement);

$mockPDO->method('lastInsertId')
     ->willReturn(1);

$mock = $this->createMock(EplanDBConnectionService::class);

$mock->method('getPdo')
     ->willReturn($mockPDO);
return $mock;
```

}